# My sql if else condition

Tags: php, mysql

```
SELECT price, sale, (IF(sale > 0) THEN ((price-sale)/price)*100 ELSE sale) AS discount FROM tbl_business_service_price
```

need help with this, don't want to calculate percentage as 100% when sales price is 0.00

Answer (score 1):

You have mixed up with `if` and `case when` syntax, usually take a look of official doc, you can get what you want.

`if` solution:

```
SELECT 
    price, 
    sale, 
    IF(sale > 0, ((price - sale) / price) * 100, sale) AS discount 
FROM tbl_business_service_price
```

`case when` solution:

```
SELECT 
    price, 
    sale, 
    case when sale > 0 then ((price - sale) / price) * 100 else sale end AS discount 
FROM tbl_business_service_price
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one out..

```
SELECT price, sale, IF(sale > 0, (price-sale/price) * 100, sale) AS discount FROM tbl_business_service_price
```